# swift 3 video playing only sound no video second time in AVPlayer

Tags: swift3, avplayer, avplayerlayer

In my application i used AVPlayer and video is playing well for first time, when i go back and again coming to player screen the layer is displaying and video sound also coming but video is not showing. Here is my Code

```
 if (videoPlaying == true) {

            videoView.isHidden = false
            let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 1)
            videoPlayer.seek(to: targetTime)
            videoPlayer.pause()
            // audioplayer = nil
            playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer)
            playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0 , y: 75 , width: videoView.frame.size.width , height:  UIScreen.main.bounds.height-170)
            playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize
            videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            let url = NSURL(string: videoString)
            let playerItem1 = AVPlayerItem(url: url! as URL)
            videoPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem1)

            videoPlayer.play()

            AppDelegate.shared().showLoading()
            // Setting slider max value
            let duration : CMTime = videoPlayer.currentItem!.asset.duration
            let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
            videoSlider.maximumValue = Float(seconds)
            videoPlayButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Pause"), for: .normal)
            videoPlaying = true
            //Adding Default Periodic Observer On Player
            videoPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { (CMTime) -> Void in


                if videoPlayer.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
                    AppDelegate.shared().removeLoading()
                    self.videoSlider.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(videoPlayer.currentTime()))
                    let currentTime : Int = Int(CMTimeGetSeconds(videoPlayer.currentTime()))
                    let minutes = currentTime/60
                    let seconds = currentTime - minutes * 60
                    self.durationLabel.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds) as String

                }
            }

        }
        else{

            videoView.isHidden = true
            let url = NSURL(string: videoString)
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url! as URL)
            videoPlayer=AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer)
            playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0 , y: 75 , width: videoView.frame.size.width , height:  UIScreen.main.bounds.height-170)
            playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize
            videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        }
```

i'm confused that do i have to remove playerlayer every time while coming to player screen? Help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please tell that what exactly you are doing in if part and in else part ???

Comment: In viewDidLoad i'm checking whether the videoplayer is playing video or not , In if condition if the video is playing then i make its seek time to zero and pause the video and again i have added playerlayer , if video not playing in background then its goes into else part, But here i'm checking videoplayer and i'm adding layer twice in if and else part. video is playing well for first time but when iam trying to play second video its showing layer but no video is visible

Comment: I have used videoPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem1) but where i'm missing do i have to remove player layer every time while playing new video if a video is already playing

Comment: you are playing same video twice or different ??

Comment: No i'm playing the different video, Even if we play same video for second time it should starts from first.

Comment: your code is really confusing and what you want , you should try to check this this might help you https://github.com/piemonte/Player

Comment: @NikunjDamani  
I'm using only one player which is declared in AppDelegate class, My requirement is First i have played a video and come back to previous page then selected the same video to play here the video should not start from beginning it should play from its current position. By using above code i can able to play video from its current position but the video content not visible for second time i can able to hear the sound, Help me why the video content is not visible for second time.